# How do I calculate S3 pricing for short-lived files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

If I understand correctly, S3 prices which say are GB/Month, are actually GB/hour right? So if I'm using S3 as a middleware between a client server and a file-generating lambda, my files would last 1-2 minutes, how can I properly calculate my costs then? The S3 calculator doesn't consider these variables...

Answer (score 4):

Per the [S3 Pricing FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/?nc=sn&loc=6):

> The volume of storage billed in a month is based on the average
>   storage used throughout the month. This includes all object data and
>   metadata stored in buckets that you created under your AWS account. We
>   measure your storage usage in “TimedStorage-ByteHrs,” which are added
>   up at the end of the month to generate your monthly charges.